# Calling Bash script from Sieve script

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, dovecot, rspamd

I'm not sure if something similar has already been asked.
I'm currently trying to push emails to our spam filter when they are moved to or out of the Junk folder so it can learn them as spam/ham. To do that I followed this guide: https://workaround.org/ispmail/stretch/filtering-out-spam-with-rspamd in the section "Learning from user actions".
The sieve scripts are created following the instructions, they have been processed by sievec and permissions have been granted following the guide. The two shell scripts have also been created accordingly. The only real difference is that we don't have the user or group "vmail". I set it to dovecot:root which should be the counterpart of our system. So the folder looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 dovecot root 4,0K Mai  7 10:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root 4,0K Jul 29  2019 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 dovecot root   85 Mai  7 10:47 learn-ham.sieve
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  246 Mai  7 10:47 learn-ham.svbin
-rw-r--r-- 1 dovecot root   86 Mai  7 10:47 learn-spam.sieve
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  250 Mai  7 10:47 learn-spam.svbin
-rw-r--r-- 1 dovecot root  509 Mär 16 13:57 mailfilter.sieve
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  398 Mai  6 18:02 mailfilter.svbin
-rwx------ 1 dovecot root   41 Mai  7 10:52 rspamd-learn-ham.sh
-rwx------ 1 dovecot root   42 Dez 14 10:42 rspamd-learn-spam.sh
```

When the sieve script executes and is supposed to call the shell scripts, I get the following errors:

```
Mai 12 17:16:28 mail dovecot[4119]: imap(user)<8778><xIGQ8nSlFMZ/AAAB>: Fatal: execvp(/etc/dovecot/sieve/global/rspamd-learn-spam.sh) failed: Permission denied
Mai 12 17:16:28 mail dovecot[4119]: imap(user)<8778><xIGQ8nSlFMZ/AAAB>: Error: write(program stdin) failed: Broken pipe
Mai 12 17:16:28 mail dovecot[4119]: imap(user)<8778><xIGQ8nSlFMZ/AAAB>: program `/etc/dovecot/sieve/global/rspamd-learn-spam.sh' terminated with non-zero exit code 84
Mai 12 17:16:28 mail dovecot[4119]: imap(user)<8778><xIGQ8nSlFMZ/AAAB>: Error: sieve: pipe action: failed to pipe message to program `rspamd-learn-spam.sh': refer to server log for more information. [2020-05-12 17:16:28]
Mai 12 17:16:28 mail dovecot[4119]: imap(user)<8778><xIGQ8nSlFMZ/AAAB>: sieve: left message in mailbox 'Junk'
Mai 12 17:16:28 mail dovecot[4119]: imap(user)<8778><xIGQ8nSlFMZ/AAAB>: Error: sieve: Execution of script /etc/dovecot/sieve/global/learn-spam.sieve failed
```

Besides the fact that I have no clue what the "server log" refers to, I just can't figure out what exactly the problem is. Sure it seems like a permission error, but how could it be fixed?

About our system: Debian 10.4 with dovecot 2.3.4.1 and pigeonhole 0.5.4
**EDIT:**
I found one mistake: I had set the sieve_pipe_bin_dir to the wrong folder. It now points to the folder containing the two .sh files, but still I get those errors:

```
Mai 22 15:40:06 mail dovecot[18547]: imap(user)<18686><57dcxDymXJ5/AAAB>: Fatal: execvp(/etc/dovecot/sieve/global/rspamd-learn-spam.sh) failed: Permission denied
Mai 22 15:40:06 mail dovecot[18547]: imap(user)<18686><57dcxDymXJ5/AAAB>: Error: write(program stdin) failed: Broken pipe
Mai 22 15:40:06 mail dovecot[18547]: imap(user)<18686><57dcxDymXJ5/AAAB>: program `/etc/dovecot/sieve/global/rspamd-learn-spam.sh' terminated with non-zero exit code 84
Mai 22 15:40:06 mail dovecot[18547]: imap(user)<18686><57dcxDymXJ5/AAAB>: Error: sieve: pipe action: failed to pipe message to program `rspamd-learn-spam.sh': refer to server log for more information. [2020-05-22 15:40:06]
Mai 22 15:40:06 mail dovecot[18547]: imap(user)<18686><57dcxDymXJ5/AAAB>: sieve: left message in mailbox 'Junk'
Mai 22 15:40:06 mail dovecot[18547]: imap(user)<18686><57dcxDymXJ5/AAAB>: Error: sieve: Execution of script /etc/dovecot/sieve/global/learn-spam.sieve failed
```

No matter which owner I set (root:root or dovecot:root, the only other users that are not "human-users" would be something like _apt, bin, nslcd, daemon, dovenull or www-data) Any idea what could cause that?

**EDIT2:**
I now changed my approach by trying to pipe directly to rspamc. Here my learn-spam.sieve script:

```
require ["vnd.dovecot.pipe", "copy", "imapsieve"];
pipe :copy "rspamc" ["learn_spam"];
```

Accordingly I changed the 90-plugin.conf to contain

```
sieve_pipe_bin_dir = /usr/bin/rspamc
```

where rspamc resides. Now I'm getting the error

```
Jun 03 09:48:34 mail dovecot[1536]: imap(user)<10486><xVI6QSmnpLN/AAAB>: Error: sieve: pipe action: failed to pipe message to program: program `rspamc' not found
Jun 03 09:48:34 mail dovecot[1536]: imap(user)<10486><xVI6QSmnpLN/AAAB>: sieve: left message in mailbox 'Junk'
Jun 03 09:48:34 mail dovecot[1536]: imap(user)<10486><xVI6QSmnpLN/AAAB>: Error: sieve: Execution of script /etc/dovecot/sieve/global/learn-spam.sieve failed
```

What went wrong? Or is the pidgeonhole pipe command only able to call shell scripts?

Comment: What user is the script executed by? If it's not `dovecot`, then they will not be able to execute the script, according to the permissions on the script files.

Comment: that's the point I'm not exactly sure about. But it can only be either dovecot or root and it was originally owned by root and it hasn't worked then either.  What would be files that should have the same owner?

Comment: I reset the owner to root:root, nothing. Same error. But I can add this line: `program '/etc/dovecot/sieve/global/rspamd-learn-spam.sh' terminated with non-zero exit code 84`

Comment: Does anybody know if the shell script could be incorporated into the sieve script? It's basically just a `exec /usr/bin/rspamc learn_ham` and the [rspamd solutions](https://rspamd.com/doc/tutorials/feedback_from_users_with_IMAPSieve.html) does something very similar, although I do not understand what they mean by _a copy of the message is placed into report_ham or report_spam folder of spam@example.com mailbox respectively_

Comment: ok, I just don't get it. Now I changed the shell scripts to include username and password to call rspamc as root, still same errors. So what's the problem?

Comment: @RichardRosner: did you solve your issue? I'm having the same problem but only for a couple users! This started after importing config and data into a new server.

Comment: @sphakka No. I even took it to the site the guide is from. I found a newer one for buster there, but someone has yet to have an idea that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems I've found what was not working: for some reason dovecot didn't seem to have execute permission on the shell scripts. So the solution was actually `sudo -u dovecot chmod +x *.sh`
So correct file permissions in my case look like that:

```
/etc/dovecot/sieve/global # ls -la
insgesamt 44K
drwxr-xr-x 2 dovecot root 4,0K Jul  8 07:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root 4,0K Jul 29  2019 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 dovecot root  144 Jun  5 10:06 learn-ham.sieve
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  306 Jun  5 10:07 learn-ham.svbin
-rw-r--r-- 1 dovecot root   86 Jun 17 15:45 learn-spam.sieve
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  250 Jun 17 15:45 learn-spam.svbin
-rw-r--r-- 1 dovecot root  509 Mär 16 13:57 mailfilter.sieve
-rw-r--r-- 1 dovecot root  462 Jul 29  2019 mailfilter.sieve~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  398 Mai  6 18:02 mailfilter.svbin
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dovecot root   41 Jun  5 10:25 rspamd-learn-ham.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dovecot root   42 Jul  8 07:33 rspamd-learn-spam.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `sieve_pipe_bin_dir` set in `90-plugin.conf` is overridden in `90-sieve-extprograms.conf`. If that is the case, you could uncomment it from `90-sieve-extprograms.conf`, or remove it from `90-plugin.conf`  and use the default directory from `90-plugin.conf` (e.g. `/usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-pipe/`)

`sieve_pipe_bin_dir` should be set to a directory name, like you originally had, not a filename of an executable.

`Permission denied` when executing the program probably means dovecot doesn't permission to read or execute the program - either the executable file or a parent directory. You can check its permissions of the executable file with `stat $file` or `ls -l $file`. `chmod +x $file` will make it executable (by all users).
You could try testing that dovecot can execute the program by running `sudo -u dovecot $file` (assuming the script doesn't do anything bad if run this way).
`$file` is e.g. `/etc/dovecot/sieve/global/rspamd-learn-spam.sh`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that didn't help. The sieve_pipe_bin_dir points at /etc/dovecot/sieve/global, seems like I've never fixed that in the OP. It's not used in 90-sieve-extprograms.conf, everything there is commented out. Executing the shellscript as dovecot actually works. So still no clue what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here are the steps I followed to get this working:

1. create your script (ie. `mail_processor.py`) in the `/usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-execute/` directory:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python3
   from sys import stdin
   with open('/var/log/mail_processor.log', 'a') as logfile:
       for line in stdin:
           print(line.rstrip(), file=logfile)
   ```

   - ensure your script and target files have correct permissions:

     ```
     $ chmod +rx /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-execute/mail_processor.py
     $ chmod 0777 /var/log/mail_processor.log
     ```
2. enable the `sieve_extprograms` plugin:

   - modify `\etc\dovecot\conf.d\90-sieve.conf`'s plugin section with the following:

     ```
     sieve_extensions = +vnd.dovecot.execute
     sieve_plugins = sieve_extprograms
     sieve_execute_bin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-execute
     ```
   - reload dovecot:

     ```
     $ service dovecot restart
     ```
3. create sieve filter (ie. in Roundcube goto `settings` -> `filters` -> `actions` -> `edit filter set`):

   ```
   require ["vnd.dovecot.execute"];
   # rule:[mail processing]
   if true
   {
       execute :pipe "mail_processor.py";
   }
   ```

Now all mail delivered to any mailbox with this sieve filter will be piped through `mail_processor.py` for action.

[Pigeonhole Sieve: Extprograms Plugin](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/sieve/plugins/extprograms/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using the common example: `pipe :copy "dovecot-lda"`.

First: Tell Dovecot where pipe executables are located.
In your 00-zzzzz.conf file, `sieve_pipe_bin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-pipe`.
This is only for 'pipe' commands in Sieve scripts. The Answer by HyperActive was for 'execute' commands.
The .conf file doesn't matter, as long as there is an !include in dovecot.conf or elsewhere that pulls in the .conf file. (90-sieve.conf, 90-sieve-extprograms.conf, etc)

Second: Restart Dovecot so that it loads that setting.

Third: Create that folder.
`mkdir /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-pipe`
I did this as root. To ensure access by other user, chmod 755 on the folder.

Fourth: Put into that folder the executable for any CLI command that you will pipe-into.
There is already a symlink for dovecot-lda, "deliver". This is a generic reference that allows us to avoid hardcoding to dovecot-lda. So I copied /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver to /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-pipe.

Fifth: Check permissions
The dovecot-lda executable itself has perms 755. Perms on 'deliver' show 777 but the actual permissions of the target can be seen with `ls -LaAFl /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver`. 755 is good for this purpose.

Summary:

- Your Sieve script says `pipe :copy`.
- Those directives are enabled with `require ["vnd.dovecot.pipe", "copy"...`.
- Any command that follows :copy needs to be defined in the folder identified by **sieve_pipe_bin_dir** in an active Dovecot .conf file, and Dovecot needs to be restarted after setting that variable.
- For the OP, that means there needed to be a symlink to 'rspamc' in /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-pipe, pointing to /usr/bin/rspamc.

OK, a couple years late, but this is for anyone else who stumbles on this Q&A.